# Annuity question from my textbook

Tags: self-learning, finance

Assuming a pensioner expects to receive an annual pension of $20,000 for the next 5 years from his former employer. What is the present worth of the pension plan?

Attempt:

I'm solving annuity questions from my textbook but this question is different from the others because there is no rate given. I don't know how to possibly go about it.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: I also agree that this question seems to be lacking information.

Comment: With this information you can only say, that the present value is $\frac{1-q^5}{1-q}\cdot \frac{1}{q^5}\cdot 20,000$ with $q=1+i$. i is the riskless interest rate.